# passing multiple id with URL using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

my requirement is passing array of ids with URL and extract them into controller method.Suppose I have the ids like below.

```
@userid=[1,2,3,4]
```

I have the `link_to` tag like below.

```
<%= link_to "update",users_update_path(:all_id=@userid) %>
```

In `users_controller.rb` file i want to access all id which are present in @userid variable.

> users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def update

end
end
```

Please help me  to resolve this issue.

Comment: <%= link_to "update",users_update_path(all_id: @userid) %>

Comment: @ pardeep :Then how can it handled in route.rb file.

Comment: put '/users', to: 'users#update'

Comment: @ pardeep : How can i extract those 4 ids in update method.

Comment: you can pass as many query parameters you want..
<%= link_to "update",users_path(all_id: @userid), method: :put %>

Answer (score 1):

convert the array into string and pass string to controller like

```
 <% c= @userid.join(‘,’) %>
 <%= link_to "update",users_update_path(:ids => c) %>
```

in controller using split method convert string back to array

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def update
     s = params[:ids]
    @ids  = s.split(/,/)
  end
end
```

in routes.rb

```
match ‘your_users_update_path/:ids’ => ‘users#update’
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I hope this will help.

```
<%= link_to "update",users_update_path(params.merge!(:all_id => [1,2,3,4])) %>

## Output
puts params[:all_id]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "update",users_update_path(:all_id => @userid.to_s) %>
```

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @user_ids = params[:all_id]
  end
end
```

Comment: @ rahulv : How to set route.rb file.

Comment: @satya: Update the question with your routes file.